# Regex to exclude string

Tags: regex

I'm not familiar with REGEX and from searching around I understand that excluding strings is not so straight forward.

Put simply I'm looking to match the string "cfc" but exclude "cfcfc".

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain why it should match `cfc`? Is that the only string it should match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with negative look ahead and look behind

```
(?<!cf)cfc(?!fc)
```

Comment: Why not `^cfc$`? There's not enough information to really know what they're trying to do.

Comment: this will match with arbitrary prefix and suffix, not just exact words.